# Failed to connect backend server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, mysql-workbench

**I can't post data in database...whenver i post data in database igot this error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" continously trying but i can't fix this probelm**

whenever i run backend server i got this error

[image]

- here is my package.json file

`

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.1.3",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^2.0.6",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-quill": "^2.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.4.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "sass": "^1.55.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:5000"
}
```

`

- here is my backend package.json file

`

```
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm start\" \"npm run client\"",
    "start": "node index.js",
    "server": "nodemon index.js",
    "client": "npm start --prefix frontend"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.0",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20"
  }
}
```

`

- here is my signup code

`

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

const Register = () => {
    const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({
        username: "",
        email: "",
        password: "",
    })
    //const [err, setError] = useState(null);
const handleChange =(e) =>{
    setInputs((prev)=>({...prev, [e.target.name]: e.target.value}))
}
console.log(inputs);
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
     const {res}= await axios.post(`{$url}/backend/auth/register`, inputs);
     console.log(res);
    } 
    catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
    return (
        <div className='auth'>
            <h1>Register</h1>
            <form>
                <input required type="text" placeholder='User Name' name='username' onChange={handleChange} />
                <input required type="email" placeholder='Email' name='email' onChange={handleChange} />
                <input required type="password" placeholder='Password' name='password' onChange={handleChange} />
                <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Register</button>
                <p>This is an error</p>
                <span>Do you have any account? <Link to="/login">Login</Link></span>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Register;
```

`

Comment: Port `5000` is already in use by another application. Try connecting to a different port number.

Comment: I have changed the port number still now it is not working and show this error
"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" AXiosError

Comment: Sometimes this problem occurs to me in the phpstorm software, to solve this problem I either close the software or restart the computer.

Comment: I restarted the laptop earlier but it didn't work.